# Show default value of innermost segment while loading D3 Sunburst

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

We are trying to display a value of innermost segment while loading d3 sunburst diagram. So when it loads for the first time, it should display sunburst diagram as:
[image]

In the current scenario, it loads as: [image]

We are referring D3 Sunburst.

Hi, Please refer jsfiddle.net/Karimjaafreh/2egqvct2 for the code. We have tried calling mouseover() function with a Path element. But it didnt work. Can you please let me know for any alternatives?

Could anyone please help me in achieving above output? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can anyone help you without the code?

Comment: Hi, Please refer http://jsfiddle.net/Karimjaafreh/2egqvct2/ for the code. We have tried calling mouseover() function with a Path element. But it didnt work. Can you please let me know for any alternatives?